# Xamarin.forms iOS 10.1 AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer exception

Tags: ios, xamarin, camera, xamarin.ios

I am building a xamarin.forms app that uses native camera. I have a custom renderer for the native camera. The current code I have works well with iOS 9.x. I just upgraded to iOS 10.1 and now the page that shows the camera control crashes. Has someone seen this before?

Following line of code (the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer constructor call) throws exception now:

```
 CaptureSession = new AVCaptureSession();
            previewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(CaptureSession)
            {
                Frame = Bounds,
                VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspectFill
            };
```

Following is the stack trace:

```
2016-11-23 22:59:27.932 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical: Stacktrace:

2016-11-23 22:59:27.933 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.933 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00012>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.933 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at AVFoundation.AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer..ctor (AVFoundation.AVCaptureSession) [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/AVFoundation/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.g.cs:95
2016-11-23 22:59:27.933 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at MyApp.iOS.CustomControls.Camera.UICameraPreview.Initialize () [0x00019] in /Users/appuser/projects/myapp-mobile/myapp-mobile-2/iOS/CustomControls/Camera/UICameraPreview.cs:70
2016-11-23 22:59:27.934 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at MyApp.iOS.CustomControls.Camera.UICameraPreview..ctor (MyApp.Core.CustomControls.Camera.CameraOptions) [0x00016] in /Users/appuser/projects/myapp-mobile/myapp-mobile-2/iOS/CustomControls/Camera/UICameraPreview.cs:30
2016-11-23 22:59:27.934 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at MyApp.iOS.CustomControls.Camera.CameraPreviewRenderer.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1<MyApp.Core.CustomControls.Camera.CameraPreview>) [0x00020] in /Users/appuser/projects/myapp-mobile/myapp-mobile-2/iOS/CustomControls/Camera/CameraPreviewRenderer.cs:30
2016-11-23 22:59:27.934 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1<TElement_REF>.SetElement (TElement_REF) [0x00110] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:167
2016-11-23 22:59:27.935 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1<TElement_REF>.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:116
2016-11-23 22:59:27.935 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x0001b] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:306
2016-11-23 22:59:27.935 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00009] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:69
2016-11-23 22:59:27.935 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x0001e] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:42
2016-11-23 22:59:27.936 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1<TElement_REF>.SetElement (TElement_REF) [0x000cc] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:155
2016-11-23 22:59:27.936 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1<TElement_REF>.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:116
2016-11-23 22:59:27.936 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x0001b] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:306
2016-11-23 22:59:27.937 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00009] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:69
2016-11-23 22:59:27.937 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x0001e] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:42
2016-11-23 22:59:27.937 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1<TElement_REF>.SetElement (TElement_REF) [0x000cc] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:155
2016-11-23 22:59:27.938 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1<TElement_REF>.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:116
2016-11-23 22:59:27.938 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x0001b] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:306
2016-11-23 22:59:27.938 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.OnChildAdded (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00009] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:69
2016-11-23 22:59:27.939 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x0001e] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementPackager.cs:42
2016-11-23 22:59:27.939 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.ViewDidLoad () [0x00086] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\PageRenderer.cs:112
2016-11-23 22:59:27.939 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00020, 0x000cc>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.940 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.940 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (intptr,intptr) <0x00012>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.940 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x00030] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:2716
2016-11-23 22:59:27.940 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.get_NativeView () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\PageRenderer.cs:48
2016-11-23 22:59:27.941 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x0004f] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\PageRenderer.cs:63
2016-11-23 22:59:27.941 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x0001b] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Platform.cs:306
2016-11-23 22:59:27.941 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.CreateViewControllerForPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page) [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:367
2016-11-23 22:59:27.942 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer/<OnPushAsync>d__44.MoveNext () [0x0000a] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:354
2016-11-23 22:59:27.942 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<bool>.Start<Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer/<OnPushAsync>d__44> (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer/<OnPushAsync>d__44&) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:471
2016-11-23 22:59:27.942 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.OnPushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool) <IL 0x00037, 0x001d3>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.942 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.PushPageAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:141
2016-11-23 22:59:27.943 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.NavigationRenderer.OnPushRequested (object,Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NavigationRequestedEventArgs) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:493
2016-11-23 22:59:27.943 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/<PushAsyncInner>d__90.MoveNext () [0x0006a] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:355
2016-11-23 22:59:27.943 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/<PushAsyncInner>d__90> (Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/<PushAsyncInner>d__90&) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:316
2016-11-23 22:59:27.944 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.PushAsyncInner (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool) <IL 0x00037, 0x001cf>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.944 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/<PushAsync>d__48.MoveNext () [0x0014c] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:179
2016-11-23 22:59:27.944 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/<PushAsync>d__48> (Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/<PushAsync>d__48&) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:316
2016-11-23 22:59:27.944 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.PushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool) <IL 0x00037, 0x001cf>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.945 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/NavigationImpl.OnPushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:436
2016-11-23 22:59:27.945 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.PushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool) [0x00013] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:109
2016-11-23 22:59:27.945 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.OnPushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool) [0x00022] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:190
2016-11-23 22:59:27.946 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.PushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool) [0x00013] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:109
2016-11-23 22:59:27.946 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationProxy.PushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:102
2016-11-23 22:59:27.946 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at MyApp.Core.Views.Common.ViewPageBase/<NavigateForward>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00022] in /Users/appuser/projects/myapp-mobile/myapp-mobile-2/MyApp/Core/Views/Common/ViewPageBase.cs:83
2016-11-23 22:59:27.947 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<MyApp.Core.Views.Common.ViewPageBase/<NavigateForward>c__async0> (MyApp.Core.Views.Common.ViewPageBase/<NavigateForward>c__async0&) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:316
2016-11-23 22:59:27.947 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at MyApp.Core.Views.Common.ViewPageBase.NavigateForward (MyApp.Core.Common.AppPageCommand) <IL 0x00026, 0x0011f>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.947 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at MyApp.Core.Views.VisitorDetailsPage/<Handle_NextButtonTapped>c__async1.MoveNext () [0x00022] in /Users/appuser/projects/myapp-mobile/myapp-mobile-2/MyApp/Core/Views/VisitorDetailsPage.xaml.cs:49
2016-11-23 22:59:27.947 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start<MyApp.Core.Views.VisitorDetailsPage/<Handle_NextButtonTapped>c__async1> (MyApp.Core.Views.VisitorDetailsPage/<Handle_NextButtonTapped>c__async1&) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:84
2016-11-23 22:59:27.948 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at MyApp.Core.Views.VisitorDetailsPage.Handle_NextButtonTapped (object,System.EventArgs) <IL 0x0001d, 0x0012f>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.948 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer.SendTapped (Xamarin.Forms.View) [0x0002e] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TapGestureRecognizer.cs:46
2016-11-23 22:59:27.948 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.EventTracker/<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<GetNativeRecognizer>b__0 (UIKit.UITapGestureRecognizer) [0x00045] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\EventTracker.cs:108
2016-11-23 22:59:27.949 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at UIKit.UITapGestureRecognizer/Callback.Activated (UIKit.UITapGestureRecognizer) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.cs:211
2016-11-23 22:59:27.949 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00022, 0x000d5>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.949 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.949 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0x00012>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.950 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
2016-11-23 22:59:27.950 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
2016-11-23 22:59:27.950 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at MyApp.iOS.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00008] in /Users/appuser/projects/myapp-mobile/myapp-mobile-2/iOS/Main.cs:18
2016-11-23 22:59:27.951 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00051, 0x001d6>
2016-11-23 22:59:27.951 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical: 
Native stacktrace:

2016-11-23 22:59:27.951 MyApp.iOS[26559:1575826] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Comment: Have you added the `NSCameraUsageDescription` permission to the info.plist? https://blog.xamarin.com/new-ios-10-privacy-permission-settings/

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion...I added the NSCameraUsageDescription permission and then it started working.